# enable/disable offline mode in andriod studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, offline-mode

How to enable/disable offline mode in android 4.0? It seems previous versions a bit different compared to current version.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To enable/disable offline mode. Go to gradle -> toggle like in this picture[image]

After clicking build gradle. You can toggle it using this toggle button.[image]

Comment: Amazing how such a minor but almost hidden setting can cause untold frustration. Surely there must exist a common description for it that can be rendered into a keyword that may be set conventionally like a true/false parameter? Something approaching gradle_tools_sync or the like?

Comment: i just didnt remember when did i turned it off lately?

Answer (score 6):

To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode (you can find something like =//=).

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3.6-gradle-offline-ui