# Android build error: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.0.2-6197926/aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-osx.jar'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-maven-plugin

I'm facing multiple issues since a week.
This is the current error: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.0.2-6197926/aapt2-4.0.2-6197926-osx.jar'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I'm using Android Studio version 4.0.2 and I did the enable/disable offline mode.

These are my grade files:

build.gradle(module: app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fithubapptrialnew"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

build.gradle(project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried invalidate cache/restart, Clean Project and Rebuild

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719726/enable-disable-offline-mode-in-andriod-studio-4-0)

Comment: did that enable/disable too. doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: set in `build.gradle` `mavenCentral` instead of `mavenLocal`

Comment: Did that. Still the same error. Gradle sync is successful but build fails and so i can't start the emulator.

Comment: This is the error in a brand new project with no changes and straight build.

Comment: then try to update Android Studio to last version, update SDK and create a new project to see if problem still occurs.

Comment: Followed the above. New version, updated SDKs, new project -> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: `Disable Gradle 'offline mode'` says, that you are still working in offline mode. Switch to online mode